# How to send file via C++

Tags: c++

I would like to ask how it could be possible to transfer a simple .csv file from one PC to another using C++.
I'm quite of new to C++, so please be patient with me ;-)

At the moment i've got a C++ program collecting data from two COM-ports and storing it (after editing) into the .csv-file mentioned above. Before windows (7 professional) is shutting down i would like to start a program which takes this file and send it to me or my webserver.
I googled around and found many postings showing FTP- or mail-scripts, but none of them worked for me...
I would prefer a FTP-solution.

Does anybody know how to realize a task like this? 
I would be very greateful for any help :-)

Comment: Read https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt and implement it. Or find a library that did.

Comment: Looks like a problem that's best solved using one of the dozens of filesync or directory sync utilities that are floating around - why do you want to implement your own solution to this rather common problem?

Comment: hmm, great idea! actually i didn't think about any solution like this... I'm just learning C++ and I'm motivated to code anything i need by myself ;-) BTW: can you recommend a smart program doing this?

Comment: use [winscp](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) and make a call to it using [system](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/)

Comment: Communication protocols aren't the best kind of programming exercise for a starter, and especially not an old clunky one like ftp.  What utility?  Too many to mention, you could check out [Syncback](http://www.2brightsparks.com/syncback/compare.html) but look at [this (closed) question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528298/rsync-for-windows), several good suggestions.

Comment: Mount the remote directory. Write the file to it. Unmount.

Comment: thanks to brian and fvu for your program-hints! @stark, how can i do this?